# Regex for 3 digits (never-mind the order)?

Tags: javascript, regex

Is there any regex (!) which can test if a string contains 3 digits  ( never-mind the order) ?

*(at least 3 digits. also I be happy to see the exact 3 solution.( if you're kind ))*

example :

```
abk2d5k6 //3 digits
abk25k6d //same here //3 digits
```

my fail tries :

```
.+?(?=\d){3}
```

Thanks.

*(only regex solutions please , for learning purpose.).*

Comment: There is. What have you tried?

Comment: Also, at most three, at least three or exactly three?

Comment: @JanDvorak Ive tried a lot. (believe me). I tried with positive look ahead but got stuck with `\d+` ( the `plus` thing. - cause the plus wants it to be sequential). for your second question , lets say at least 3. ( sorry for not clarify it).

Comment: @RoyiNamir: If you've tried things, show what you've tried, why you thought that was the way to go, and the results you were getting that weren't what you expected.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, for the learning purpose, I suggest to read through this very comprehensive [tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html).

Otherwise, the JavaScript regex would probably look something like this:

if you want to make sure that there are at least three digits:

```
/^(?:\D*\d){3}/
```

Or if you want to make sure that there are exactly three digits:

```
/^(?:\D*\d){3}\D*$/
```

`\D` is any non-digit character. `*` allows 0 or more of those. `\d` is any digit character. `{3}` repeats the subpattern 3 times. And `^` and `$` mark the start and end of the string, respectively.

Comment: No need to use non-capturing ;-)

Comment: @JanDvorak there is never a need to use non-capturing. It's always just an optimization. And I guess it's better practice to only use capturing when there is need for it, instead of the other way round.

Comment: Funny we still call them "regular" expressions, isn't it?

Comment: @Kos what do you mean? Sure there are non-regular constructs in pretty much every regex engine, but how does this apply to this answer?

Comment: @Kos regexes match non-regular languages only if back-references are involved.

Comment: @JanDvorak or balancing groups or recursion ;)

Comment: @m.buettner or anything else flavor-specific ;-)

Comment: @RoyiNamir well, you have to match the characters between the digits somehow. Otherwise you end up with the answer that was deleted ;). Or do you mean something else?

Comment: No it is fine. ( I dont see any other way - beside [^0-9] which is the same thing) . thank you.

Comment: @RoyiNamir sure there are other ways. `^(?:.*(?=\d)){3}.+$` for instance, but they don't really help increasing readability ;) (or performance, I guess)

Comment: @m.buettner I must say I don;t undertsand the second solution. HOw the last `\D` make it work ( at least) ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir my first solution does not include `$`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20062/discussion-between-royi-namir-and-m-buettner)

Answer (score 3):

You could also do something like this:

```
str.match(/\d/g).length >= 3
```

This is dead simple, and very clearly shows the intent without a complicated regex.

This isn't tuned for speed though.

Comment: Although the question states that it's asking specifically for a regex for learning purposes, I really like the simplicity of this one. +1!

Comment: It still uses a regex though, but only technically. I provided it only for an alternate use of regex to solve the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Given your comment that you want "at least" three digits, I don't think it needs to be any more complicated than:

```
/\d.*\d.*\d/
```

...which is a digit, then zero or more of anything, then another digit, then zero or more of anything, then another digit. As I haven't anchored either end, there's an implicit "zero or more of anything" at both ends.

```
console.log(!!"abk2d5k6".match(/\d.*\d.*\d/));  // true
console.log(!!"abk25k6d".match(/\d.*\d.*\d/));  // true
console.log(!!"abkd5k6".match(/\d.*\d.*\d/));   // false (I removed a digit)
console.log(!!"abk2k6d".match(/\d.*\d.*\d/));   // false (I removed a digit)
```

or

```
/(\d.*){3}/

console.log(!!"abk2d5k6".match(/(\d.*){3}/));  // true
console.log(!!"abk25k6d".match(/(\d.*){3}/));  // true
console.log(!!"abkd5k6".match(/(\d.*){3}/));   // false (I removed a digit)
console.log(!!"abk2k6d".match(/(\d.*){3}/));   // false (I removed a digit)
```

or at m.buettner points out in the comments below, rather than `.` you can use `\D` (not a digit):

```
/\d\D*\d\D*\d/
```

or

```
/(\d\D*){3}/

display(!!"abk2d5k6".match(/\d\D*\d\D*\d/));  // true
display(!!"abk25k6d".match(/\d\D*\d\D*\d/));  // true
display(!!"abkd5k6".match(/\d\D*\d\D*\d/));   // false (I removed a digit)
display(!!"abk2k6d".match(/\d\D*\d\D*\d/));   // false (I removed a digit)

display(!!"abk2d5k6".match(/(\d\D*){3}/));  // true
display(!!"abk25k6d".match(/(\d\D*){3}/));  // true
display(!!"abkd5k6".match(/(\d\D*){3}/));   // false (I removed a digit)
display(!!"abk2k6d".match(/(\d\D*){3}/));   // false (I removed a digit)
```

Basically, no need for anchors if it's an "at least" match.